# Measurement protocol for checkout steps

Tags: google-analytics

We have implemented transaction tracking using Measurement protocol. Works as a wonder 100% of transactions are tracked.

In the checkout we have option for people to login via Facebook oauth. GA attributes all the transactions to Facebook if people login via Facebook.

I was wondering if it is an option to take out GA code from checkout and create funnel using measurement protocol page views. Which should be very stable and we will solve Facebook oauth issue.

Later on we will implement product impression, product click, promo click tracking using data layers and GTM.

Do you think such approach would work?